# Reordering a factor variable in R

Tags: r

I am using the relevel function to reorder the factor levels, and want to check: when the relevel function is used, is the only the order changed, and not the actual ordinal v value assigned to the level?

```
    data$age_factor        <-factor(data$DMV_AGECAT)
    levels(data$age_factor)
    levels(data$age_factor)[levels(data$age_factor) == "1"] <-"< 65"
    levels(data$age_factor)[levels(data$age_factor) == "2"] <-"65-75"
    levels(data$age_factor)[levels(data$age_factor) == "3"] <-">=75"

    #relevel
    data$age_factor    <-relevel(data$age_factor, ref = 2)
    levels(data$age_factor)
```

For example - 65-75 becomes the "first" level, but it is still "2" correct?

Comment: you could use `as.numeric()` to check for yourself ... (If I recall correctly, the underlying numeric index *does* change. ) Could we have a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect, ordinal value is exactly what determines the order of the levels. If you change one, you change the other.

Quick demonstration:

```
x = factor(c("a", "b"))
y = relevel(x, ref = 2)

## you can see the "1" value is assigned to "a" in `x`
## but switches to "b" in the releveled `y`
data.frame(x, as.numeric(x))
#   x as.numeric.x.
# 1 a             1
# 2 b             2

data.frame(y, as.numeric(y))
#   y as.numeric.y.
# 1 a             2
# 2 b             1
```

Generally, I would avoid using the level number whenever possible.